# Can SMALL TCP segments slow the TCP transfer rate?

Tags: tcp

Hello everybody and thanks for reading me,

I have a datacenter switch connected to 10 25G servers and running some sort of storage application (nsdperf), the problem is that we are seeing a very slow transfer rate (compared to the 25Gb available).
The slow transfer rate is not experienced IF the traffic does not need to go through the switch. In such a case, TCP can get full bw (or something very close to that).

I generated a simultaneous packet capture and from the 3-way handshake and I can see WS=256, SACKs allowed bidirectionally and an estimated RTT equal to 89 microseconds.

[image]

This is a layer 2 communication (same vlan) so the switch is basically doing a simple layer 2 lookup only. Moreover, we don't see any packet dropped on the switch (discards/drops) and we don't see any indication of buffering those packets on the switch (If there are no drops, there's no reason to buffer any of these packets).

One thing I noticed is that there is a lot of TCP segmentation, it might look like as if the complete transfer were part of the same BIG TCP SEGMENT because each new segment points to the previous one:

```
[2 Reassembled TCP Segments (407 bytes): #1377693(305), #1377696(102)] <<<\n
[2 Reassembled TCP Segments (629 bytes): #1377696(603), #1377698(26)] <<<<\n
[2 Reassembled TCP Segments (745 bytes): #1377698(207), #1377701(538)] <<<<\n
```

Even though the complete packet size is close to the MTU (1500), as you can see above the TCP segment size is very small, could that be a problem? (overhead on the server?).
We can see that this problem gets worse as traffic increases (we don't see packet loss in that scenario either).

Thanks for your time

Comment: A switch has no say in MSS determination unless it filters/drops frames with even less than the standard Ethernet payload of 1500 bytes. Possibly that application/tool is extremely latency-sensitive. Have you tried another (type of) switch? Have you tried another tool (like iperf)?

Comment: Yes, using another switch the application reports a much better tcp transfer rate, this analysis is to find out what might go different when traffic is going through this switch.
Sorting by "delta displayed previous frame" the biggest latency I can see is 1 ms, then the average is 400 microseconds (not even a millisecond), bty some of the values on this column are negative can't understand why the delta from prev pkt could be a negative integer but that is a diff story

And forgotm to mention that, the RTT from the 2 way handshake is around jsut 89 microseconds

Comment: The gap between frames isn't the latency. With Gigabit Ethernet you can get a maximum-size frame each 12.3 µs at wirespeed. What's so special on that switch? Any specs? Special requirements? Special processing?

Comment: The MSS is set on the sending TCP by the receiving TCP in the handshake. Each side can set set a different MSS.

Comment: Nothing special about these switches: Nexus 9000 and DELL Z9100, both using 25 gig interfaces to each server.
There are no special requirements on the app, actually, this is a stress test. The application NSPERF is used to put stress on the switch using storage traffic (read/write operations)